# How do I remove an element from a doubly circular linked list properly?

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I have to implement a doubly circular linked list using my own constructor, I am pretty much done but can not figure out why the remove method is not working.

I have done plenty of research but I have had difficulties finding anything that matches my needs. The problem is that I do not have a permanent head and tail pointer, like usually in a doubly linked list but must work with the "header" as the starting as well as the ending point.

Constructor with the header element

```java
public MyDoubleLinkedList() {
        header = new DEntry(0, null, null);
        header.next = header;
        header.previous = header;
        size = 0;
    }
```

Inner class for the listEntrys

```
    class DEntry {
        /** the data element represented by this entry */
        private final int data;

        /** reference to the previous element in the list */
        private DEntry previous;

        /** reference to the next element in the list */
        private DEntry next;

        /**
         * @param data     the data object this entry represents
         * @param previous reference to the previous element in the list
         * @param next     reference to the next element in the list
         */
        public DEntry(int data, DEntry previous, DEntry next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.previous = previous;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
```

Method to add to the list:

```java
    /**
     * Adds a new element into the list at the position specified
     * 
     * @param position the 0 based position at which to add the passed value
     * @param value    the value to add
     * @return 0 if adding was successful, -1 if not
     */
    public int add(int position, int value) {
        // TODO: please put your code here
        DEntry listEntry = new DEntry(value, null, null);

        DEntry temp = header;
        int i = 0;

        if (position < 0 || position > size) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (position == 0) {
            temp = header;

        } else {
            while (i < position) {
                temp = temp.next;
                i++;
            }
        }

        listEntry.next = temp.next;
        listEntry.previous = temp.next;
        temp.next = listEntry;
        temp.next.previous = listEntry.next;
        size++;

        return 0;
    }
```

Method to remove from the list

```java
    /**
     * Removes an element at the position specified from the list
     * 
     * @param position the 0 based position of the value to remove
     * @return value of the removed entry if removing was successful, -1 if not
     */
    public int remove(int position) {
        // TODO: please put your code here

    DEntry toBeDeleted = header;

        if(position < 0 || position > size) {
            return -1;
        }
        if(getEntry(position) == null) {
            return -1;
        } else {
        toBeDeleted = getEntry(position);
        }

        int dataOfDeletedNode = toBeDeleted.data;

        if(position == 0) {
            header.previous.next = toBeDeleted.next;
            header.next.previous = toBeDeleted.previous;
        } else if(position == size){
            toBeDeleted.previous.next = header.next;
            toBeDeleted.next.previous = toBeDeleted.previous;
        } else {
            toBeDeleted.previous.next = toBeDeleted.next;
            toBeDeleted.next.previous = toBeDeleted.previous;
        }



        size--;
        System.out.println(dataOfDeletedNode);
        return dataOfDeletedNode;
    }
```

If I run the code

```java
list.add(0, 10);
list.add(1, 20);
list.add(0, 30);
remove(1); // 10 should be deleted
```

Instead of 30, 20 I get just 20.

Comment: As an aside, is there any reason for using that while loop instead of `DEntry toBeDeleted = getEntry(position);`? You're looping until that's the effect anyway, so why not do it in one step?

Comment: Also note that the body of `if (position == size)` will never be executed - you've already checked that `position` is strictly less than `size`.

Comment: yes, getEntry(position) does exactly that, but I reached a point where I was desperate enough to try everything. Will change it asap tho! Thanks for the tip on the size restriction too!

Comment: I'd also check that the result *before* you call `remove(1)` is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Printing the list before the remove call puts out: 30, 10, 20. Seems right to me. It somehow cuts off the the previous element of the removed element too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem in the meantime. It was indeed my add method that prevented my remove method to work properly.

Partially at fault was my while loop which stopped at (i

Here is what I came up with on the add method, and everything is workin fine.

```
public int add(int position, int value) {

    // Creates a new listEntry 
    DEntry listEntry = new DEntry(value, null, null);
    DEntry temp = header;

    int i = 0;

    if (position < 0 || position > size) {
        return -1;
    }

        while (i <= position) {
            temp = temp.next;
            i++;
        }

    // setting the elements neighbours
    listEntry.next = temp;
    listEntry.previous = temp.previous;

    // placing the new element between last and next
    temp.previous.next = listEntry;
    temp.previous = listEntry;

    // places the new entry in the list
    temp = listEntry;
    size++;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your main problem's source is add method. Actually, there is a great problem in linking new nodes in your code and that was the only problem I have detected by reading your code. Thus, your add method should be something like this:

```
public int add(int position, int value) {
    DEntry listEntry = new DEntry(value, null, null);

    DEntry temp = header;

    if (position < 0 || position > size) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (position == 0) {
        temp = header;

    } else {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < position) {
            temp = temp.next;
            i++;
        }
    }

    listEntry.next = temp.next;
    listEntry.previous = temp;
    temp.next = listEntry;
    size++;

    return 0;
}
```

1. listEntry would be the next node after the temp one. Then it's previous pointer should point to the temp.
2. putting new node after a temp node does not need any change in previous link of the temp. So, the last linking you had in your code was problematic.

Comment: Thank your very much! Your are right. The list works very well if I f.e. add elements like this: list.add(0, 10); list.add(1, 20); list.add(2, 30); and then remove one at a specific position. However, if I add every element at position 0, and then remove the element at position 3, it removes the element at position 3 and all elemnts linked before that too.

Comment: it can be understood from your above comment that there is a conflict between your data structure index and the size variable you are using. The size variable's range is [1,...] but your data structures' range is [0,...]. it is weird that you have 3 instances in your list which are from index 0 to two and you delete the instance at index 3. please double check this issue and let me know about it if possible.